# Swapping adapters inside the ConcatAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-concatadapter

I need to swap two adapters inside the `ConcatAdapter` but the list of adapters that is returned by `getAdapters()` is immutable and won't let me use the `java.util.Collections` utility.

So far what I've tried was to turn that list into a mutable list, swap the items and set the list back but it's ugly to look at since I'm doing this inside the `ItemTouchHelper`'s callback.

Would copying the class from the source and make that list mutable instead work? Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do some hacky stuff with reflection, the ConcatAdapter class doesn't hold a reference to the underlying adapters but there's a ConcatAdapterController field (which class is private) that has a `mWrappers` field which is basically the one returned by `getAdapters()`

Anyway here's the code I've used and it's working fine

```kotlin
val controllerClass = Class.forName("androidx.recyclerview.widget.ConcatAdapterController")
    val controllerField = ConcatAdapter::class.java.declaredFields.find { it.name == "mController" }?.apply {
        this.isAccessible = true
    }
    val controller = controllerField?.get(this)
    val wrappersField = controllerClass.declaredFields.find { it.name == "mWrappers"}?.apply {
        this.isAccessible = true
    }
    val wrappers = wrappersField?.get(controller) as List<*>

    Collections.swap(wrappers, from, to)

    notifyItemMoved(from, to)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the Anti-pattern of hitting private API fields with reflections, we can exchange the underlying data of both adapters and then `notifyItemChanged()`.

An adapter in the `ConcatAdapter` has a data class item, you can expose it to caller to be modified.

Here's a demo:

```
// we need to swap adapter at pos1 with adapter at pos2 from contactAdapter
private fun swapAdapters(pos1:Int, pos2:Int) {

    // assuming the RV adapter is MyRVAdapter, and holds "data" field
    val adapter1 = concatAdapter.adapters[pos1] as MyRVAdapter
    val adapter2 = concatAdapter.adapters[pos2] as MyRVAdapter

    // Exchange adapters data
    val data1 = adapter1.data.copy()
    val data2 = adapter2.data.copy()
    adapter1.data = data2
    adapter2.data = data1

    // reflect the change
    concatAdapter.notifyItemChanged(pos1)
    concatAdapter.notifyItemChanged(pos2)
}
```